# Why mail send as spam message

Tags: php

if you had solution please help me to fix it. please? mail was sent but it always visible on spam message. so how i keep it for inbox. please check my code deeply and give me right answer for matching my code.
i used this point i create user login part and i want to give user to recovery option. then user will try to recovery i will send user to mail.

```
<?php
            session_start();
             mysql_connect(***, ****, ***);
              mysql_select_db('*****');
              $email = $_POST["email"]; 
              $_SESSION["email_id"]=$email;
              $a = rand(100,999999);
               //echo $a;
                $_SESSION["random"]=$a;
             $to = $email;
             $subject = "Verification Code";
             $message = 
                            "<!DOCTYPE html>
                            <html>
                                <head>
                                    <title></title>
                                </head>
                                <body>
                                    <h2 style='color:#000CA5;'>Your Verification code is : </h2><br><h2><b>$a</b></h2>
                                </body>
                            </html>";
             $header = "From:****@**.com \r\n";
             $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
             $header .= "Content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
             $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header);
             if( $retval == true ) {
               // echo "Message sent successfully...";
                $sql = "update random set ran_num='$a' where emailid='$email'";
                mysql_query($sql);
                IF(!mysql_query($sql)){
                die("erroe processing :".mysql_error());
            }
            else{
                echo "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> location.href='password_update.php' 
                </script>";
            }  
             }
          ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into updating your DNS records with an SPF record.

You can do this by adding the following as a TXT record. It will let email clients know the IP of your A record and the SPF records of your MX servers are allowed to send emails using that domain name.

`v=spf1 a mx ~all`

You can add a specific ip with `ip4:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` as well.

Ex: `v=spf1 a mx ip4:127.0.0.1 ~all`

If you need more complex rules or wish to read more into it, you should read through the [SPF Record Syntax](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax).

Almost every email client checks a domain's SPF record as part of it's spam check. [Here's the description Google gives about the SPF Record and why having it is important](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en):

> We recommend that you create a Sender Policy Framework (SPF) record
>   for your domain. An SPF record is a type of Domain Name Service (DNS)
>   record that identifies which mail servers are permitted to send email
>   on behalf of your domain.
>
> The purpose of an SPF record is to prevent spammers from sending
>   messages with forged From addresses at your domain. Recipients can
>   refer to the SPF record to determine whether a message purporting to
>   be from your domain comes from an authorized mail server.
>
> For example, suppose that your domain example.com uses Gmail. You
>   create an SPF record that identifies the G Suite mail servers as the
>   authorized mail servers for your domain. When a recipient's mail
>   server receives a message from user@example.com, it can check the SPF
>   record for example.com to determine whether it is a valid message. If
>   the message comes from a server other than the G Suite mail servers
>   listed in the SPF record, the recipient's mail server can reject it as
>   spam.